# Rails Query limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a query of pictures like this

```
pictures = Picture.near([latitude, longitude], 6.8).where("created_at >= :time",{:time => time })
```

and I took out the tags which is associated with this model (every picture `has_many :tags`) like so

```
@tags = Tag.find(:all, :conditions => ["picture_id in (?)",pictures.collect(&:id)])
```

I used a query to pull out an attribute of each tag

```
@tags.map(&:tagcontent)
```

What I need to do is limit the results of the tags that come out. so I replaced

```
@tags = Tag.find(:all, :conditions => ["picture_id in (?)",pictures.collect(&:id)])
```

with this

```
numoftags = 6
tags = Tag.limit(numoftags).find(:all, :conditions => ["picture_id in (?)",pictures.collect(&:id)])
```

but this only yields 4 tags, when I know there is least 6 that can be pulled out. How should I modify this function.

Comment: Please post from your logs the SQL query that your code is generating.

Comment: @jdl sorry, im not sure where i can find that

Comment: RAILS_ROOT/log/development.log (or whatever environment you're running this under)

Comment: @jdl i can't find the query it's generating there

Comment: What Rails environment are you using?

Comment: You can do it in IRB too: `Tag.limit(num).where(etc).to_sql`. But you need to avoid `find(:all)` for this to work. Use a regular `where`: `Tag.limit(numoftags).where(:picture_id => pictures.map(&:id)).to_sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 3.X you can do something like this (using Arel)

```
numoftags = 6
@tags = Tag.where(["picture_id in (?)",pictures.collect(&:id)]).limit(nooftags)
```

Comment: this raised errors elsewhere in my app (which i fixed, but had to leave out your solution), but that was completely my fault for not explaining well enough, but this solved exactly what i asked for